# Why does this code sometimes report 21.3 FPS when I ask for 30 FPS?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl, frame-rate

I have the code below (a bare-bones version of Nehe tutorial 1 ported to JOGL 2.0) that is requesting an FPSAnimator that animates 30 FPS.  When I run the code, it prints 21.321962 or 21.413277 FPS.  When creating the FPSAnimator, as you can see, I specify 30 frames per second is desired.  This is on a modern machine with a Core i7 CPU, 24GB of RAM, and an ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series graphics card.  21.3 FPS does not appear to be a limit either.  When I raise or lower the requested FPS, the reported FPS does go up and down (though it doesn't appear to be a linear relationship).

However, sometimes when I run the code on the same machine is gives me 30.30303 FPS.  In both cases I have nothing but a few web browser tabs and eclipse open on the machine.  It is also worth noting that this doesn't only happen in this simple example, it happens in all of my JOGL based applications.  I have merely provided this simple example to demonstrate the issue.

I've seen this issue on a few machines.  Maybe it's just my imagination, but it doesn't seem to occur on machines with NVidia GeForce cards, but I have seen it happen on machine's with ATI cards and NVidia Quadro FX cards.

What could be causing this difference?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GLCanvas glCanvas;
    FPSAnimator animator;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOGL HelloWorld");
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);

    caps.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    caps.setHardwareAccelerated(true);
    glCanvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
    glCanvas.setSize(800, 800);
    glCanvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    glCanvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, int x, int y,
                int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
            FPSAnimator animator = (FPSAnimator) gLDrawable.getAnimator();
            System.out.println("animator.getLastFPS(): "
                    + animator.getLastFPS());
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(glCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    animator = new FPSAnimator(glCanvas, 30, false);
    frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    animator.setUpdateFPSFrames(10, null);
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: If you have compositing on disable that and try again.

Comment: @genpfault Can you kindly explain what compositing is and where I would disable it?

Comment: [Compositing window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) tend to use [VSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync) to prevent tearing.  Unfortunately VSync also tends to quantize your FPS to discrete values like 60, 30, and 20.  This is especially annoying if your application can't quite hit the 60FPS deadline, at which point it will drop to 30.

Comment: @genpfault If I read the wiki right, that can be disabled in Win 7 by using Windows Basic display settings.  I tried that and Windows Classic and the issue still persisted.

Comment: Try disabling VSync (system's and application's) completely, just so we can be sure the problem isn't VSync. ## By your systems specs, I'm guesstimating you could run simple 2D animations far faster than 30 FPS even without hardware acceleration and double/triple buffering. Give it a try with `caps.setDoubleBuffered(false);` and `caps.setHardwareAccelerated(false);`, see if there is any difference, so that we get some more clues what/where the problem is and/or isn't. ## Lastly, just to make sure, your BIOS and drivers (mainly video-card's) are all up-to-date, right?

Comment: @TheLima All drivers and such are up-to-date, or at least within a few months.  Turning off HW acceleration and double buffering caused no difference.  Interestingly, Julien at the JOGAMP forums suggested I should use fixed-rate scheduling (true for the 3rd parameter to the constructor).  This did cause the frame rate to be correct, but I don't want frames to get queued up if they are missed.  It sounds like they don't like FPSAnimator, so I'm not sure why it isn't deprecated or something as it does not seem reliable.

Comment: Oh so the 3rd parameter was not "fullscreen" as I was thinking! I don't use JOGL directly (I use Slick, which uses LWJGL, which I'm unsure if uses JOGL internally. "o_O), so I was thinking the constructor had `container, targetFPS, fullScreen` as params. ___ As for the reliability, what I'm reading here [ http://java.net/jira/browse/JOGL-205 ] suggest that it's actually the other-way-around, which the fixed-rate at `false` being the "villain", and causing drift and FPS problems, while `true` gives better accuracy and reliability, but consumes more resources.

Comment: Yep, backed up by the information on this page [ http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2008/jw-09-opensourcejava-jogl.html?page=7 ], I am now confident to say using the fixed-rate scheduling flag `false` was your problem, and using it `true` is your fix. ___ I'm writhing a proper answer to address that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably is being caused by an inaccuracy related to `java.util.Timer.schedule()`, which JOGL uses when initialized with any two-param constructors, or when the 3rd param, which is a flag for using *fixed-rate scheduling*, is set to `false`.

---

When the flag is set to `true`, FPSAnimator will use `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` instead, being considerably more consistent and accurate in terms of FPS.

In specifics, using the flag as `true` will be particularly better in higher FPS, as the default is weak to delays and would begin to suffer from drifting, while using *fixed-rate scheduling will execute an animation the correct number of times over a lengthy period, regardless of delays* [[source]](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2008/jw-09-opensourcejava-jogl.html?page=7).

---

Note however that, according to the response to the [ticket responsible for this functionality being implemented](http://java.net/jira/browse/JOGL-205), it is *unclear whether the flag will cause excessive CPU consumption.*

Comment: This is correct, and when I use `true` the problem goes away.  However, I really don't want to have fixed rate scheduling.  Lets say that 1 frame takes 1 second to render (the rest all take < 1ms).  After that frame finally renders, 30 additional frames will fire off almost immediately.  In this scenario I want it to wait 1/30 of a second before firing off the next frame.  This is what setting the boolean to false is supposed to provide for me.

Comment: So I just looked into this even more, and I compared 2 TimerTask's scheduled with .schedule and .scheduleAtFixedRate on this same machine.  Sure enough, it took 1/21.3 seconds when I used .schedule and about 1/30.3 seconds when I used .scheduleAtFixedRate.  So your answer is completely right, the problem is not JOGL or the framerate, it is with `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Requested 30 fps is not guarantied. FPS will be almost always lower or higher, but avg fps will try to be as requested.

VSync can be enabled via gl.setSwapInterval(1), Have nothing to do with windows settings.

Use animator.setUpdateFPSFrames(200, System.out); to print avg fps each 200 frames

Comment: For the frame-rate to be varying by almost 10 FPS off target, I don't think the issue here is as simple as the normal FPS fluctuation, although it indeed exists. ## I also don't think it's VSync, unless it's synchronizing to a rate equal or below 30 FPS (far below 60 FPS), which is quite rare these days for a desktop platform like he seems to have.

Comment: I used that to print the average, the results were the same.  I also tried setSwapInterval(1) and there was no change at all.  I'm not sure if I was supposed to add that in init, reshape, or what, but I put it in a few places and it did not seem to affect anything.